# Issue with rotation when generating a procedural mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I feel like I'm just hitting a mental block on figuring out this issue, so I thought I'd check in for advice on my code.

I'm attempting to generate a road mesh that's a fairly simple/consistent shape. The issue is, that it won't rotate properly while using Transform.forward and Transform.right commands to adjust the points from the center.

Here's a simplified version of how I'm calculating the vertices (slopes and slanting has been removed):

```
CreateRoadPiece ( Transform _transform, Vector3 center )
    {
        Vector3 p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11;

        p0 = center + _transform.forward - ( _transform.right * 5.0f );
        p1 = center + _transform.forward + ( _transform.right * 5.0f );

        p2 = center + ( _transform.right * 5.0f );
        p3 = center - ( _transform.right * 5.0f );

        p4 = center - _transform.forward - ( _transform.right * 5.0f );
        p5 = center - _transform.forward + ( _transform.right * 5.0f );

        p6 = p0;
        p7 = p1;
        p8 = p2;
        p9 = p3;
        p10 = p4;
        p11 = p5;

        p0.y -= 0.1f;
        p1.y -= 0.1f;
        p2.y -= 0.1f;
        p3.y -= 0.1f;
        p4.y -= 0.1f;
        p5.y -= 0.1f;

        p6.y += 0.1f;
        p7.y += 0.1f;
        p8.y += 0.1f;
        p9.y += 0.1f;
        p10.y += 0.1f;
        p11.y += 0.1f;
    }
```

The _transform is the object with the mesh component and it's rotated and positioned to face the direction the road strip should lay out on.

A road piece is 10 units wide, 0.2 units tall and 2 units deep.

I had assumed using transform.forward and transform.right would solve for rotation issues, but maybe I'm missing something?

It all works without issue when facing Z+.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: why would anyone vote to close this? it's the only good Unity3D question in a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to this. I had figured out that the calculations were (mostly) correct, but the positioning was off. It was mostly throwing Transform.TransformPoint and all variations (Direction, Vector and their Inverses) at the calculations in the above, as well as of the center variable, but I finally managed to reach something that worked as I needed.

```
CreateRoadPiece ( Transform _transform, Vector3 center, byte unitDirection )
{

        Vector3 transformForward = _transform.TransformDirection( _transform.forward );
        Vector3 transformRight = _transform.TransformDirection( _transform.right);

        if( unitDirection == 1 || unitDirection == 3 )
        {
            transformForward = -transformForward;
            transformRight = -transformRight;
        }

        p0 = ( center + ( transformForward + ( -transformRight * 5.0f ) ) );
        p1 = ( center + ( transformForward + ( transformRight * 5.0f ) ) );
        p2 = ( center + ( transformRight * 5.0f ) );
        p3 = ( center + ( -transformRight * 5.0f ) );
        p4 = ( center + ( -transformForward + ( -transformRight * 5.0f ) ) );
        p5 = ( center + ( -transformForward + ( transformRight * 5.0f ) ) );
}
```

Unity's Mesh system seems to only work in world space, but I use the Transform's rotation for other checks (traffic direction when creating paths mostly). So this solution seems to solve my placement issues quite nicely (I also use:

```
_transform.InverseTransformPoint ( center );
```

when I send the center value to this function.

EDIT:

Modified the code slightly to what my current solution is. unitDirection is a byte value to tell if the rotation is 0 (0), 90 (1), 180 (2) or 270 (3) (all pieces are only rotated by 90 degrees to make combinations simpler (intersections mainly)). The order was reversed on 90 and 270 degree rotations so the adjustments made to transformForward and transformRight put everything where it should be.